# Request.IsAuthenticated not working in IE repeated partial view MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have strange problem with an MVC3 application. The application works as expected on Firefox and Chrome but not IE.

I have a partial view that is repeated in a loop on a page. At the bottom of the partial view I am doing a check on Request.IsAuthenticated. If authenticated an ajax form should display. This works on all browsers but IE. In IE if there is more than one instance of the partial view rendered the form does not appear (even when the user is logged in).

I have attached the partial view code below. The form is right at the bottom.

Has anyone else had a similar problem? Any help or thoughts would be great. Thank you

```
@using HERE_MVC.Extenstions
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@model HERE_MVC.Models.TilesModel
@{
    Layout = String.Empty; 
}
@foreach (var t in Model.NearestTiles)
{     
    <div id="div_tile @t.TileId" style="float: left; height: 235px; width: 300px; border: 0px solid black; margin: 5px;
        background-color: #DDDDDD;">
        <div id="tile @t.TileId" style="background-image: url(@Url.Action("GetTileBgImageWithCache", "Account", new { userName = @t.aspnet_Users.UserName })); background-repeat:no-repeat; height: 200px; width: 300px; border: 0px solid black;">
            @t.aspnet_Users.UserName
            <br />
            @t.Title
            <br />
            @t.Quote1
            <br />
            @t.UpdatedDateTime
        </div>
        <div id="collectbtn @t.TileId" style="padding-top: 5px;">
            @Html.ActionImage("Profile", "Home", new { userName = @t.aspnet_Users.UserName }, "~/content/img/Profile-Icon.jpg", "View Profile", "25")
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (@User.Identity.Name == @t.aspnet_Users.UserName)
                {
                }
                else if (!Model.CheckAlreadyFollowing(@User.Identity.Name, @t.aspnet_Users.UserName))
                {         
                @Ajax.ActionImageLink("../content/img/add.jpg", "Collect Tile", "25", "imgOn1" + @t.aspnet_Users.UserName, "AddFollowedUser", "Home", new { userToFollowName = @t.aspnet_Users.UserName }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "  $(#imgOn1" + @t.aspnet_Users.UserName + ").hide();" })
                }
                else
                {  
                @Ajax.ActionImageLink("../content/img/minus.jpg", "Drop Tile", "25", "imgOff2" + @t.aspnet_Users.UserName, "UnFollow", "Home", new { userToUnFollowName = @t.aspnet_Users.UserName }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
                }
            }
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@t.ShareLink&t=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" onclick="PopupCenter('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=@t.ShareLink&t=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)', 'NearRoar - Facebook',680,400); return false;" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">
                <img src="../../Content/img/Facebook-share.jpg" width="25px" alt="Facebook share" /></a>
            <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=@t.ShareLink&media=@t.PintrestShareImage&description=@t.PinterestShareText" onclick="PopupCenter('http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=@t.ShareLink&media=@t.PintrestShareImage&description=@t.PinterestShareText', 'NearRoar - Pin It',600,400); return false;" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none" target="_blank">
                <img border="0" src="../../Content/img/pintrest.jpg" title="Pin It" width="25px" /></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-hashtags="@t.TwitterHashTag,NearRoar" data-url="@t.ShareLink" data-count="none" data-lang="en">
            </a>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="msg_list">
            <p class="msg_head @t.TileId">
                Comments (<span id='commentCount '@t.TileId>@t.CommentLines.Count</span>)</p>
            <div class="msg_body">
                @foreach (var c in t.CommentLines)
                {
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <div class="msg_body_comment_item_image">
                            <img width="50" src="@Url.Action("GetImageWithCache", "Home", new { userName = @c.aspnet_Users.UserName })"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="msg_body_comment_item_text">
                            @c.CommentLine1
                            <br />
                            @c.CommentTime
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                <div id="newComment @t.TileId">
                </div>
                <div id="formdiv @t.TileId">
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <div>
                        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Comment" + @t.TileId, "Home", new { tileId = @t.TileId }, new AjaxOptions { }, new { id = "form" + @t.TileId, name = "form" + @t.TileId }))
                        {
                        <fieldset>
                            @Html.TextBox("commentText " + @t.TileId, null, new { @class = "msg_body_comment_text_input", maxlength = 200 })
                            <input type="hidden" name="date" id="cmTimeHidden @t.TileId"  value="" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="commentText" id="commentTextHidden @t.TileId"  value="" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" onClick="setHiddens(@t.TileId);setNewComment(@t.TileId);"/>
                        </fieldset>
                        }
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would double check that rendered markup is valid. It's possible that one of your IDs is duplicated and that IE is just kicking it away.

UPDATE: You have 4 elements with ID t.titleId. As I said above, you can have only one specific ID on the HTML page. Move this to class instead and all should be fine.

Comment: So are yu talking about ids set like this... id="cmTimeHidden @t.TileId"?

Comment: This should still be unique as the string is concatinated with a starting string. Can an id have a space in it?

Comment: If you have id="cmTimeHidden @t.TileID" it means that this element has two IDs. One is cmTimeHidden and the other is value of @t.TileID. So basically if you have space in a id attribute value, it makes two or 3 or 4 IDs(depending on number of spaces)

Comment: OK I understand now. So if I want to join those parts together how would I do it? If I have no space in between the parts MVC doesn't insert the id, instead the id would be cmTimeHidden@t.TitleID, not cmTimeHidden6

Comment: yeah that will work. you can do cmTimeHiddnen-@t.TitleID. Then you can easily split it with jquery if you need the id of the element. And this way you'll have only unique IDs on the page.

Comment: Ahh you use the '-' character, great stuff, I will try it now. Thank you.

Comment: did you try User.Identity.IsAuthenticated instead?